# Training the tenserflow js model with a large amount of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

**Good day everyone and thank you for taking the time to answer my question.**

I am using node js, docker, redis bull, postgresql, tenserflow js to write a project to train an AI model. My server has **12 CPU cores** and 16GB of RAM.

The problem occurs after following these steps.

1. I make a two-dimensional data array of **10080** elements for input data for training and an array of **5040** elements for output data. all data are numbers
2. Using redis bull, I create queues that retrieve this data from the database, prepare it for training, and train the model synchronously using **.fit()**.
3. I used queues to divide the learning process **evenly across CPU cores**.

Problems:

1. For some reason, the system uses only **one CPU core**, and just as I see from monitoring, the training packages are too large and clog 100% of this CPU core.

Maybe I should use .dataset() and worker threads? I need to train madel with 10080 input data packets. when the size of the entire database is about 5TB of data With one core I will train the model for a year and a half with all this data(((
I don't understand how to split the training across all possible CPU cores. **I will answer any questions and will be grateful for any advice**

There is some my code:

```
 trainQueue.process(1,  (payload, done) => {
      const train = async()=>{
      try {
        // console.log(payload.data);
        const test = await trainTask(payload, done);
        if (test) {
          console.log("Done!");

        } else {
          throw new Error("Не тут то было!")

        }
        done();
      } catch (err) {
        done(err);
      }
    }
    train()
    });


 for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
      await delay(100)

  
     trainQueue.add(q[i], 
       {
       jobId: `Burger#${Number(new Date())}`,
       attempts: 5,
       backoff: 300000,
       delay: 1000,

    // })

    }
```

```
module.exports = async (payload, done) => {
    try {
        // STEP 1.bun

        console.log(payload.data.bun);
        payload.log(`Start Training, ${payload.data.sym}`,);
        const model = await train.GetModel(payload)
        if (!model) {
            throw new Error("Model not found")
        }
        payload.progress(5);
        // await delay(2000)
        const data = await train.GetLastData(payload, payload.data.qtyitems, payload.data.sym)
        payload.log(data.length)
        payload.progress(15);

        if (payload.data.qtyitems == data.length) {
            payload.log(new Date(Number(data[0].open_time)))
            payload.log(new Date(Number(data[data.length - 1].open_time)))
            payload.log((data[0].trained))
            payload.log((data[data.length - 1].trained))
            const { dataset, labels } = await train.PrepareData(payload, payload.data.qtyitems, data)
            payload.progress(25);

            const { datasetTenser, labelsTenser } = await train.getTensers(payload, dataset, labels)
            payload.progress(50);

            const trained = await train.Train(payload, model, datasetTenser, labelsTenser)
            const rr = data.splice(data.length / 2)
            payload.progress(75);

            const UpdateData = await train.UpdateData(payload, data)
            payload.progress(100);


        } else {
            throw new Error('Не то количество минут, которое ожидали')
        }

        // await delay(3000)

        await payload.progress(100);
        // done();
        return true
    } catch (err) {

        console.log("Error")
        return done(err);
    }
}
```

```
  const t = await model.fit(dataset, labels, {
        epochs: 3,
        batchSize: 32,
     
      });

    
      await model.save('file://model-js')
      payload.log('Сохранил модель!')

      tf.dispose(model)
      tf.dispose(dataset)
      tf.dispose(labels)
```

Comment: There are some articles that suggest you need the WASM backend : https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/09/supercharging-tensorflowjs-webassembly.html